# How to use react hooks in effective way?

Tags: react-hooks

Currently I am learning react. can anyone tell me what is the main application usage of react hooks and how can we take more advantage of using hooks with react.?

Comment: I think this question is too broad for StackOverflow, but you can check out the original [Hooks keynote](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=685) talk which explains the motivation and has a lot of examples of using hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, before if a component had state or needed to utilize a lifecycle method, we had to use a class, which requires a bunch of extra code.

Now that is not the case. With hooks, instead of ever having to use a class, we could just always use a function.

Tyler McGinnis wrote good blog post about it here

https://tylermcginnis.com/why-react-hooks/